# How to generate Bootstrap DatePicker datesDisabled dynimcally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Working with Django and Ajax. 
I have used Ajax to get my dynamic dates, now the issue is feeding the dates to the `datesDisabled: []` array.

When i `alert(data)` i get my dates alerted perfectly. Now i just need to pass the array to the datesDisabled.

```
<script>
    (function($) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#id_unit").change(function () {
            let unit_id = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: {% url 'unit_booked_date' %},
                data: {
                    'unit': unit_id,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    return data
                }
            })
        });


        $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            allowClear: true,
            datesDisabled: [
                data
            ],
        });
    });
    })(window.jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar issue where I tried to fetch minDate and maxDate dynamically.

You need to destory the datepicker and re-initialize with new properties

Following is what worked for me.

```
...
('.input-group.date').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
...
```